# How to merge two dictionary in python if the keys already exist, the values of keys is not changed?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have merged two dictionaries, but I want if the keys in the dictionaries already exist then the value of the keys is not changed.

Right now, In my code, the value of the keys changed.

I used this code

```
a={'saya': 2,'menolak': 2,'omnibus': 3,'law': 3,'dan': 1,'tetap': 1,'di': 1,'sekolah': 1,'diperintahkan': 1,'untuk': 1,'tidak': 1,'layak': 1}

b={'omnibus': 0,'law': 0,'meningkatkan': 0,'kesejahteraan': 0,'saya': 0,'setuju': 0,'diterapkan': 0}

def add_dict(a,b):
    a.update(b)
    return a

add_dict(a,b)
```

The result:

```
{'saya': 0,
 'menolak': 2,
 'omnibus': 0,
 'law': 0,
 'dan': 1,
 'tetap': 1,
 'di': 1,
 'sekolah': 1,
 'diperintahkan': 1,
 'untuk': 1,
 'tidak': 1,
 'layak': 1,
 'meningkatkan': 0,
 'kesejahteraan': 0,
 'setuju': 0,
 'diterapkan': 0}
```

I want the result like this:

```
  {'saya': 2,
     'menolak': 2,
     'omnibus': 3,
     'law': 3,
     'dan': 1,
     'tetap': 1,
     'di': 1,
     'sekolah': 1,
     'diperintahkan': 1,
     'untuk': 1,
     'tidak': 1,
     'layak': 1,
     'meningkatkan': 0,
     'kesejahteraan': 0,
     'setuju': 0,
     'diterapkan': 0}
```

Comment: If you want to preserve the values of `a`, why not flip the arguments in call? Like this: `add_dict(b,a)`?

Comment: I want to keep the index. If I use add_dict(b,a). I think the index will change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a loop and check each key in `b` before adding the value to `a`.

```py
def add_dict(a,b):
    for key in b:
        if key not in a:
            a[key] = b[key]

    return a
```

---

Edit: If you want to keep some values from `b` instead of `a` even if the key is already in `a` you can add a third argument to `add_dict` with a list of keys. Then in the loop, you check if the key is in this list and use the value from `b` instead of `a` if it is.

This results in (I have added a docstring, in NumPy style, for clarity)

```py
def add_dict(a,b, force_add=None):
    """
    Add key/value pairs from `b` into `a`. If a key is in `a` and in `b` its
    value is not added to `a`, unless it is in force_add`.

    Note: this modifies dictionary `a`

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : dict
        The first dictionary
    b : dict
        The second dictionary
    force_add : list, optional
        A list of keys in `b` whole values will be added to `a` even if `a`
        already has the key

    Returns
    -------
    dict
        The first dictionary after it was modified.
    """
    if force_add is None:
        force_add = []

    for key in b:
        if key not in a or key in force_add:
            a[key] = b[key]

    return a
```

Now if you do `add_dict(b, a, force_add=["saya"])` you will get

```
{'omnibus': 0, 'law': 0, 'meningkatkan': 0, 'kesejahteraan': 0, 'saya': 2, 'setuju': 0, 'diterapkan': 0, 'menolak': 2, 'dan': 1, 'tetap': 1, 'di': 1, 'sekolah': 1, 'diperintahkan': 1, 'untuk': 1, 'tidak': 1, 'layak': 1}
```

Comment: if I reverse ( merge b a, but I wanna keep the index {'saya': 2,
     'menolak': 2,..)  what is it possible? thank you

Comment: You want to add the content of a dictionary into another one, with the caveat the "conflicts" (keys in both dictionaries) will be resolved as "keep the value of the first dictionary". Now you are asking for a way to specify an exception such that some "conflicts" woll be resolved as "keep the value of the second dictionary". That is just a small change in the if.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setdefault which updates only if key doesn't exist:

```
for i in b:
    a.setdefault(i, b[i])

print(a)

{'saya': 2, 'menolak': 2, 'omnibus': 3, 'law': 3, 'dan': 1, 'tetap': 1, 'di': 1, 'sekolah': 1, 'diperintahkan': 1, 'untuk': 1, 'tidak': 1, 'layak': 1, 'meningkatkan': 0, 'kesejahteraan': 0, 'setuju': 0, 'diterapkan': 0}
```

Comment: Thank you buddy,  how about if I reverse ( merge b a, but I wanna keep the index {'saya': 2,'menolak': 2,..)  what is it possible? thank you

Comment: What do you mean? Order has no importance for dictionaries. What values do you want to keep?